# Чтение данных с профиля в соцсетях

Tags: ajax

Как зарегистрироваться и получить динамическую информацию (например, для почтового сервиса это может быть количество новых сообщений, для twitter – количество подписчиков), используя асинхронный Ajax запрос?

Comment: смотрел я api в разных соцсетях , но там указаны методы уже для зареганых пользователей или просмотра данных без регистрации, пример:
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/usejquery.json?callback=?', function(json) { // получение информации о пользователе @ usejquery 
 $('#twitter_followers').text(json.followers_count); // получение числа фоллоуверов из json объекта и размещение в <span>
 });
}); 
можт у кого то есть пример с регистрацией! заранее искренне благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Либо через ajax мониторить, либо в сторону node.js копать

Comment: можете поделится примером ?

Answer (score 0):

Почти у каждой социалки есть API.
Почитай, там есть и  Ajax  и php библиотеки.

Comment: смотрел я api в разных соцсетях , но там указаны методы уже для зареганых пользователей или просмотра данных без регистрации, пример: $(document).ready(function() { $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/usejquery.json?callback=?', function(json) { // получение информации о пользователе @ usejquery $('#twitter_followers').text(json.followers_count); // получение числа фоллоуверов из json объекта и размещение в <span> }); }); можт у кого то есть пример с регистрацией! заранее искренне благодарен